# Can you add an Integer to a loaders instance name?

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

My project is a slideshow of sorts. I load multiple files and display them one at a time. Unlike most slideshows, each of the loaded files are combinations of SWF's, Jpegs, and Video. My code is a little much to put here, so i'll just put what relates to the problem with my "idea" thrown in.

Here's what i want to do. This code is not accurate, but it might show what i'm wanting to do. However i can't seem to find the correct method of doing it. Overall i would like to put a dynamic number into the name of my loader for each slide. That way i can load, and unload/null the loader so the content is completely removed from my project.

As of now my project runs fine, however it has some memory leaks that i cannot track down. I've checked all Eventlisteners, also even calling "kill" functions within the loaded swf's that unload/removes/null's everything. Still getting these leaks.

Thanks for any help

var i:Number;
i = 0;

```
function loadSlideData():void
{
    curSlide[i].load(new URLRequest("Slides/"+ slideXML.image[slideInt].@file));
    curSlide[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, DisplaySlide, false, 0, true);
}

function DisplaySlide(event:Event):void
{
    curSlide.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, DisplaySlide);

    slideLength.delay = slideXML.image[slideInt].timeDelay.@seconds*1000;
    slideLength.start();

    addChild(curSlide);

    curSlide.alpha = 1;
    curSlide.x = (1150-1000)/2;
    curSlide.y = (700-460)/2 - 30;

    slideLength.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, zoomOut,false,0,true);
}

function zoomOut(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    slideLength.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, zoomOut);
    if(slideInt == slideXML.image.length()-1)
    {
        slideInt=0;
    }else{
        slideInt++;
    }
    slideLength.stop();
    TweenLite.to(slideArray[randomSqareNum], .75, {y:sqrOriginalY, x:sqrOriginalX, scaleX:1, scaleY:1, ease:Circ.easeInOut,onComplete:zoomIn});
    TweenLite.to(curSlide, .25, {alpha:0, ease:Circ.easeInOut,onComplete:removeCurSlide});
    trace(curSlide);
    }

function removeCurSlide():void
{   
    trace(curSlide);
    i++;
    var curSlide[i]:Loader = new Loader();
    loadSlideData();
}
```

Comment: What seems strange to me is that for every slide you create a new Loader, that will have to be added to the Stage. What happens with the other loaders? If you don't remove them from the Stage, that's probably where your leaks come from.

Comment: I agree with LexLythius. If you don´t remove the loaders, removing the EventListeners doesn´t make a change, since a reference is saved within the loaders.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make much sense:

```
 var curSlide[i]:Loader = new Loader();
```

Are you asking how to store loaders in array?
I am not sure if this will give you an idea ... this:

```
function removeCurSlide():void
{   
    trace(curSlide);
    i++;
    var curSlide[i]:Loader = new Loader();
    loadSlideData();
}
```

Should be more like:

```
var slideArray:Array = [];

function removeCurSlide():void
{   
    trace(curSlide);
    i++;
    var curSlide:Loader = new Loader();
    slideArray[i] = currSlide;
    loadSlideData();
}
```

You would need to replace all the other 'curSlide' to 'slideArray'

Here is some nice explanation how arrays work:
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3arrays/